# Out of memory reading after reading 682 txt files

Tags: c#, streamreader

I want to read a file with this code but after 682 times i get this error:

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(scanpad[lusteller]);
```

scanpad is an array with the filepaths and lusteller is counter for it.
Scanpad excists 11207 files.

I have also have looked en there is a file on place 682

Anyone a solution?

Here the full version of my code

```
        using (StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(scanpad[lusteller]))
        {
            //do stuff

            lengte = bestandsnaam.Length;
            lengte = lengte - 13;
            controller = bestandsnaam.Remove(lengte, 13);           // controllertype uit naam halen
            do
            {
                rij = file.ReadLine();
                if (rij != null)              //error op volgende lijn vermijden
                {
                    if (rij.StartsWith("0") || rij.StartsWith("1") || rij.StartsWith("2") || rij.StartsWith("3"))
                    {
                        rijcheck = true;
                    }

                    teller = teller + 1;
                    if (teller > 10)
                    {
                        if (rijcheck == true)           // rij is datumlijn
                        {
                            string[] split = rij.Split(' ');
                            foutinformatie[0, index] = type;                     //type ophalen
                            foutinformatie[3, index] = controller;              //controllernaam ophalen
                            foutinformatie[1, index] = split[0];                //datum ophalen
                            foutinformatie[2, index] = split[1];                //tijd ophalen 
                            foutinformatie[4, index] = split[2];                //foutcode ophalen
                            foutinformatie[5, index] = split[5];                //foutteller ophalen 
                            if (controller.StartsWith("MPU") == true)
                            {
                                lusarraygraad = 5;
                                while (lusarraygraad < 360)
                                {

                                    if (graadmpu[0, lusarraygraad] == split[2])
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            graad = graadmpu[1, lusarraygraad];
                                            foutinformatie[7, index] = graad;
                                        }
                                        catch
                                        {
                                        }
                                        lusarraygraad = lusarraygraad + 499;
                                        graadgevonden = true;
                                    }
                                    lusarraygraad = lusarraygraad + 1;
                                }
                                foutinformatie[7, index] = graad;
                                if (graadgevonden == false)
                                {
                                    foutinformatie[7, index] = "";
                                }
                                graadgevonden = false;
                            }

                            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            if (controller.StartsWith("AAUX") == true)
                            {
                                lusarraygraad = 4;
                                while (lusarraygraad < 30)
                                {

                                    if (graadaaux[0, lusarraygraad] == split[2])
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            graad = graadaaux[1, lusarraygraad].ToString();
                                            foutinformatie[7, index] = graad;
                                        }
                                        catch
                                        {
                                        }
                                        lusarraygraad = lusarraygraad + 499;
                                        graadgevonden = true;
                                    }
                                    lusarraygraad = lusarraygraad + 1;
                                }
                                foutinformatie[7, index] = graad;
                                if (graadgevonden == false)
                                {
                                    foutinformatie[7, index] = "";
                                }
                                graadgevonden = false;
                            }
                            if (controller.StartsWith("ACTRL") == true)
                            {
                                lusarraygraad = 6;
                                while (lusarraygraad < 85)
                                {

                                    if (graadactrl[0, lusarraygraad] == split[2])
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            graad = graadactrl[1, lusarraygraad].ToString();
                                            foutinformatie[7, index] = graad;
                                        }
                                        catch
                                        {
                                        }
                                        lusarraygraad = lusarraygraad + 499;
                                        graadgevonden = true;
                                    }
                                    lusarraygraad = lusarraygraad + 1;
                                }
                                foutinformatie[7, index] = graad;
                                if (graadgevonden == false)
                                {
                                    foutinformatie[7, index] = "";
                                }
                                graadgevonden = false;
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                telleromschrijving = 6;
                                informatie = "";
                                while (split[telleromschrijving] != " ")
                                {
                                    informatie = informatie + " " + split[telleromschrijving];
                                    telleromschrijving = telleromschrijving + 1;
                                }
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                foutinformatie[6, index] = informatie;                //foutteller ophalen 
                            }
                            rijcheck = false;
                            rij = file.ReadLine();
                            while (varcheck < 40)
                            {
                                // rij met eerste variable

                                if (rij != "")
                                {
                                    variable[indexlokaal, varteller] = rij;
                                    foutinformatie[varteller + 8, index] = variable[indexlokaal, varteller] = rij;
                                    varteller = varteller + 1;
                                    rij = file.ReadLine();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    foutinformatie[varteller + 8, index] = " ";

                                    varteller = varteller + 1;
                                }
                                varcheck = varcheck + 1;
                            }
                            varcheck = 0;
                            varteller = 0;
                            indexlokaal = indexlokaal + 1;
                            index = index + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            while (rij != null);
            file.Close();
            file.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: sounds like your not using `using`

Comment: Do you work the streams simultaneously?

Comment: Could you post more of the code you are using, for example the loop you are using?

Comment: What do you with the contents of the file after you have read it? If you are saving contents of each file into memory e.g. save into array of strings, you ought to get a OOM exception.

Comment: Check the length of string you are creating, I believe fragmentation is the main issue. Also you may be holding lots of string in 'foutinformatie' array

Comment: Foutinformatie is big enough

Comment: Please show the declaration of `foutinformatie`. "Big enough" might mean "too big" when it's populated with lots of strings. Also, where do you declare `index`? When is it reset to zero?

Comment: Now there is too much code. Most of it is irrelevant. But the problem is probably in the surrounding loop.

Comment: I love this part of your code: while (rij != null); How long do you want to wait?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine 682 is just a number where you happen to be running out of memory, not a special number. you should encapsulate your streamreader into

```
using(StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(scanpad[lusteller]))
{
//do stuff
}
```

This way, your streamreader is disposed of after being used, clearing memory

**EDIT FOR UPDATE**

Inside your streamreader you also have

```
                        rij = file.ReadLine();
                        while (varcheck < 40)
                        {
                            // rij met eerste variable

                            if (rij != "")
                            {
                                variable[indexlokaal, varteller] = rij;
                                foutinformatie[varteller + 8, index] = variable[indexlokaal, varteller] = rij;
                                varteller = varteller + 1;
                                rij = file.ReadLine();
                            }
```

but you are not checking if `ReadLine` is returning null again, looking at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx

This can also cause a outofmemory exception as your stream has reached null and yet you have continued onwards

Comment: this gives me the same problem

Comment: edit your question to show an update... (perhaps more about how this line is used too!)

Comment: Updated answer.. (edit as a sidenote, you dont need file.Close and file.Dispose anymore as using handles this

Comment: just try `if (rij == null){break;}`

Comment: _can also cause a outofmemory exception as your stream has reached null_  - not very likely. It might give NulReference exceptions.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - you are right I had originally misread msdn... user, you are going to have to set breakpoints and find out what line of code it is failing on, look on google for setting conditional breakpoints, or post your stack trace

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you do with the StreamReader.

First of all you need to dispose it, but I don't believe it's the issue as the GC would have collected it before running out of memory (unless you also hold a reference to it).

If you use something like "ReadToEnd" and the content of the files is large you hit Large Object Heap with the strings created (and if you manipulate them by creating sub-string it can get worse).
After a while the heap becomes fragmented so you run out of memory because it is unable to find large enough memory chunk for your request.

Well, that's my guess with little info into your code, good luck.

Comment: +1ed for the read to end, I didn't believe this was the problem as I couldn't imagine anyone wanting to read in 11207 files that were of different sizes, so I assumed they were all individual but equally sized files

Comment: Maybe he is scanning data files to insert data into a DB, or something like search in files.. there are many scenarios and frankly scanning 11K files of exactly same size seems unlikely to me :)

Comment: I am scanning files to put them in a sql databse. But i must have every line of the txt file

Comment: Check the amount and the lengths of the string you are generating there. String larger than 40K will hit large object hip and create fragmentation. If it the case you need to use byte arrays and not strings and reuse fix length buffers. Or streams if possible...

Answer (score 0):

Try use `Using`:(disposed memory after read)

```
using(System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(scanpad[lusteller]))
        {

        }
```